# BeautifulSoup: Get all children as a string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there an elegant way do this without getting the contents list and then joining them?

I want to get everything inside a tag like this:

Input: `<p>asd <b>fasd</b>sda</p>`

output: `asd <b>fasd</b>sda`

The other solutions are less elegant:

1. Get soup.contents and then join all the elements in the list together
2. use soup.encode_contents which returns a byte string with the correct output 
   it returns `b'asd <b>fasd</b>sda`

Comment: So why not decode the `soup.encode_contents` result again?

Comment: And why is `soup.contents` less elegant? `' '.join([str(e) for e in a.contents])` not short enough?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: I mean not elegant as in I think there might be a way to straight up get the contents in string form since most HTML parsers have that capability.

Comment: But BeautifulSoup doesn't store the HTML as text. It stores an object model.